# php SoapClient remove slashes

Tags: php, soap-client

I'm having trouble with SoapClient.
In my requests to webservice there are some special symbols, like @, $, ', etc.
When I'm adding it to `$params` array, SoapClient add slashes to it. But remote webservice worked on win-platform and do not remove slashes and returns error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a problem they need to fix on their end rather than you to change your code...

If the above is not possible for some reason, you can build your XML request and send it manually, but that's is a bad practice. Another way is to use some alternative to SoapClient, e.g. http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap (this library is really simple to use). Not 100% sure it escapes special symbols automatically, but it doesn't escape "<" and ">" on its own, so I'd say it's worth trying in your case.

Or I'd also try to enable forced UTF-8 conversion in SoapClient to see if that changes things:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://foobar.com/webservice.asmx?WSDL', array('trace' => 1, 'encoding'=>' UTF-8'));
```

Comment: I can't to say fix this problem on provider side. :(
What you mean on "manually XML requests"? Do it through my own class and override __doRequest method?
Thanks, will try nusoap, I think about it, but I want to use client from the box it is bit better then using something else.

Comment: I mean compose your own XML as string and send it to server, effectively yes, writing your own implementation :( Have you tried 'encoding' parameter by the way?